# Using Boost to_utf function with not uniform encoding name

Tags: c++, boost, character-encoding

Can I use

```
boost::locale::conv::to_utf
```

function like this:

```
std::wstring wide_string = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<wchar_t>(str, encodingName);
```

if `encodingName` is not uniform (`Utf8` instead `UTF-8`, or `latin1` instead `iso-8859-1`)?

How I can get uniform encoding name from its synonym?

Comment: Have you tried? What does the documentation say?

Comment: If I replace `iso-8859-1` by `latin1`, then `to_utf` throw a exception with string `Invalid or unsupported charset:latin1`.

Comment: There is ucnv_getCanonicalName function in ICU Library -- http://site.icu-project.org/

Comment: I saw that one (actually a family of ~4 functions) in a minute of googling, I didn't have enough time to check that these names would somehow work for Boost Locale (although I know that Boost Locale optinoally compiles on top of ICU). If you test it and find it works, please post as an answer!